# Terraform IBM - iam_role_crn for service instance alias

Tags: terraform, ibm-cloud, terraform-provider-ibm

I am trying to provision some IBM Watson Assistant services using the terraform provider for IBM.
I am currently using the **ibm_service_instance** along with **ibm_service_key** resources from the IBM provider.
The relevant piece of terraform code can be found below.

```
# create service
resource "ibm_service_instance" "wa_test_service_instance_name" {
  count = var.wa_template_service_counter
  name = "Test-${var.wa_test_service_instance_name}-${var.app_name}-${count.index + 1}"
  space_guid = var.space_guid
  service = var.service_offering
  plan = var.plan
}

# create credentials
resource "ibm_service_key" "wa_test_service_key" {
  count = var.wa_template_service_counter
  name = var.service_key_name
  service_instance_guid = ibm_service_instance.wa_test_service_instance_name[count.index].id
  depends_on = [ibm_service_instance.wa_test_service_instance_name]
}
```

The service instance is created successfully along with the credentials and the CF alias. The problem is that for the CF alias, the created credentials are not having **iam_role_crn** **manager** which is the required setup in my configuration.
[image]

If I manually add the credentials from IBM cloud dashboard for the CF alias, they are created with the **iam_role_crn** Manager. Also, the resource instance for which is this alias has in its credentials **iam_role_crn** = Manager.

I could not find a way of specifying such a parameter when the **ibm_service_key** or **ibm_service_instance** gets created.
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/IBM-Cloud/ibm/latest/docs/resources/service_key

Is there a way to create the credentials for the alias of the service with this parameter **iam_role_crn** setup as Manager or is there a work-around to achieve this?

Comment: Do you need to have the service available for Cloud Foundry? I would try to create Watson Assistant as regular resource, using the resource API. Then you add credentials via https://registry.terraform.io/providers/IBM-Cloud/ibm/latest/docs/resources/resource_key

Comment: Yes, I need the service available for Cloud Foundry.